# Use custom image for Azure then deploy Python app to it

Tags: docker, azure-web-app-service, podman

Can I use a custom Docker image for my Python webapp in Azure, and then deploy my python application to that container through a pipeline?
We need a specific tool to run the Python app so we can not use the default Azure container as it does not meet the requirements for that tool.

I do not want to add my Python web app to the image itself.

I created an image and depoyed that one but the logs in Azure say

'Container XXX didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 80, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.'

I then added a "EXPOSE 80" section to my Dockerfile but then I get no logs at all.

Comment: If your application isn't in the image, how does it get deployed?  Why not include it in the image?

Comment: Can you please share your `Dockerfile` and what tool you want to use to run the python app?

Comment: @DavidMaze I do it through a pipeline in Azure for the other Web apps we have.

Comment: @VivekVaibhavShandilya We want to use PyAudio, [this is the docker file](https://pastebin.com/CqvfXeZJ)

Answer (score 0):

To Check logs of Azure webapps running on container
you need to enable `App Service Logs` and then you can see logs in `Logs Stream`.

- Open deployed Web App
- Select `App Service Logs` in `Monitoring` section on the left side panel
- Enable to `File System` and Click on save
- Open `Log Stream` (below `App Service Logs`)
- it will take some time to connect and after that you will be able to see you app logs

[image]

[image]

I have created a simple Flask app

**`app.py`:**

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')

def hello():
    message = "Greetings! Wecome to Flask App"
    return message

app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

**`Dockerfile`:**

```
FROM python:3.11-alpine3.19

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5000:5000

ENTRYPOINT [ "python","app.py" ]
```

## `OUTPUT`:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I didn't want to do. I know how to create an image with the python app in it.

Comment: I tried to deploy using github pipeline into the docker conatiner after setting up the image [dockerfile](https://i.imgur.com/1FN3p9Y.png). deployment is successful [1](https://i.imgur.com/JVU5JO6.png). But I don't think it is possible as file are not being copied to container which is resulting in [error](https://i.imgur.com/QbZKo3i.png)